# Formatting numbers in html : adding space between millions (like : 9 999 999)

Tags: html, string, formatting, numbers, space

I need to display a number in HTML with spaces between its millions, is there any easy formatting that allows to do so?

I want to display 999 999 999, instead of 999999999

Comment: You cannot use HTML to format the number in the way you want. Any solution would require the use of JavaScript.

Comment: @dwayne is it possible to do so in angularJS?

Comment: Yes, it will also be possible to do using AngularJS. You can write a custom filter. [Here are some that already exist.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter)

Comment: Can i use JQuery/JavaScript? It has better solution.

Comment: @divy3993 yes you can use JQuery/JavaScript. In fact, the solution I give below uses plain old JavaScript. In the case of AngularJS, you can take my plain old JavaScript and wrap it up in a filter and use that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I stated in my comment. You will not be able to format the number in the way you want using HTML. You will have to use JavaScript.

[Here is how you would do it using plain JavaScript](http://jsbin.com/fudalu/edit?html,js,output).

For reference:

```
function formatNumber(n) {
  if (n < 0) { throw 'must be non-negative: ' + n; } 
  if (n === 0) { return '0'; }
  
  var output = [];
  
  for (; n >= 1000; n = Math.floor(n/1000)) {
    output.unshift(String(n % 1000).padStart(3, '0'));
  }
  output.unshift(n);
  
  return output.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: With this code, 308039 will be output as 308 39.

Comment: @TerjeNesthus and Eirik Rindal thank you for pointing out the failing cases. I've updated the code to fix those problems.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer yields wrong results if you ha an number like 123000456 (if I had more point it would have been a comment...)

Comment: Please make sure to delete this as soon as you can comment.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use PHP to generate the HTML how you would like it displayed, or, alternatively you could use Javascript as Dwayne above has stated. Unfortunately, HTML (or CSS) has no way of formatting numbers like you want.

Check out PHP's number_format() function:
http://php.net/number_format

For Javascript, there's a few options (I searched for 'Javascript number currency format' in Google):
http://numeraljs.com/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help, indeed it helps me do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner version:

```
[..."1230000456"].reverse().reduce((acc, v, i) => acc.push((i + 1) % 3 == 0 ? " " + v : v) && acc, []).reverse().join("").trim();
```